# NextJS 13 Dynamic Routes - Firebase Hosting Deployment issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting, next.js13

I have a problem with dynamic routes. I use App Routes from NextJs13 to define routes.

Here is my **firebase.json** code:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1",
      "maxInstances": 2
    },
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Here is **next.config.js** code:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    trailingSlash: true,
    experimental: {
        serverActions: true,
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

My dynamic path looks like this:
**app/projects/[slug]/page.tsx**

If i try to open this location on deployed website i see message:
***Service Unavailable***

Would you like to be kind and try to help me? Thank you :)